# Wildcard on empty string

Tags: java, mysql

I am creating a Java program that interfaces with a mysql database for a school project:
I am using java mysql connector to execute the following query when the user hits the search button through a GUI:

```
public ResultSet getBooks(String book_id,String title,String author)
{
    ResultSet rs = null;
    try{
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
        rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT book_id,title,author_name,branch_id,no_of_copies   FROM "
                + "(temp_author NATURAL JOIN book_copies) "
                + "WHERE book_id like '%"+book_id+"%' OR title like '%"+title+"%' OR author_name like '%"+author+"%';");

    }
    catch(SQLException ex) {
        System.out.println("Error in connection: " + ex.getMessage());
    }
    return rs;
}
```

The problem with this query is that if any of the fields (book ID , title or author) are empty, the query returns true as result.
So my question is how do I use the wildcard to search for a matching string but return a null set when the strings (boook_id,title or author) are empty.

Thank you.

PS: I wasn't able to post an image of the GUI due to my low reputation.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. You may add an example or post some more code.

Comment: I just added the whole function. does it make sense now ?

Comment: so if I understand it correctly, you just have to check whether the strings are empty and only a new `OR` part if there is content in the string. Is this what you want to achieve?

Comment: yes that's what I want to check. i could do a if(book_id.equals("")) in Java but that would be a lot of combinations ( there are other similar queries I need to write that have even more columns) . So I'm trying to ask if there's a way I could do this in mySQL code (or lesser java code)

Comment: will your strings be empty or null?

Comment: @sailingthoms: strings will be empty

Comment: check out my solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your `book_id` `String` is not `null`, you could this:

```
WHERE ('"+book_id+"' <> '' AND book_id like '%"+book_id+"%') OR 
      ('"+title+"' <> '' AND title like '%"+title+"%') OR 
      ('"+author_name+"' <> '' AND author_name like '%"+author+"%')
```

I recommend you to use prepared statements also (for safety!).

Comment: Only 1 of (book_id, title, author_name) has to be non-empty. It could be any one, two being non-empty or all three being non-empty

Comment: @AjayKarthik I updated my answer to show all of them.

Comment: @AjayKarthik .. and another small update; let SQL check your variables.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand how do I let "SQL check my variables" ?

Comment: @AjayKarthik that's what my answer does. The part where is it says `'"+book_id+"' <> ''` for example.

Answer (score 0):

Just do something like this and include and statements with the rest of your arguments

```
If (isNull(title)&&isNull(author)&&isNull(book_id)) return null;
```

Comment: I doubt they are `null`, as that would generate a runtime error in the string concatenation. You could would write `if ("".equals(title)) ...`. But that doesn't fix it, as this needs all of them to be not-empty, which is not the case.

Comment: The strings aren't null, they could by empty of the form ("") or not empty